# Setting UILabel text from rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I have two view controllers 1.rootviewController 2.myStatusDisplayViewController.

I have c stack call back function which returns a c string.That particular call back function calls a function in my rootviewcontroller. In my rootview controller I have reference to myStatusDispalyViewController using that reference I'm trying to update the label in myStatusDisplayviewController.

```
app.myStatusDisplayViewController.displayCallStatus.text =updatedCallStatus;
[app.myStatusDisplayViewController viewDidLoad];
[app.myStatusDisplayViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
```

Comment: Jeeva are you setting text in Dispatch.Queue.main?? actually your problem is not 100% understandable

Comment: @DheerajD im completely new to objective c..so i dont know about DIspatch.queue.main.above code changes my label text but it is not getting updated in screen.but when i click some other buttons my label gets the updated string.i want to refresh my viewcontroller label without clicking my buttons.i hope u got my point..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your text in that block:

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     app.myStatusDisplayViewController.displayCallStatus.text =updatedCallStatus;
        });
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: k wil give a try can u explain about dispatch_async or reference link to that method..

Comment: Can you please let me know in which method you are setting the text?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1